# Icon is shown in FlyoutItem but not in Tabbar on Bottom

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a problem with my Images. I have added some Images to my solution, for the Flyoutitems.
The Images are shown in th Flyout but not in the tabbar in the bottom.

AppShell.xaml

```
<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
            <ShellContent Title="News" Icon="tab_feed.png" Route="NewsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewsPage}" />
            <ShellContent Title="Über den Verein" Icon="tab_team.png" Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
            <ShellContent Title="Termine" Icon="tab_calendar.png" Route="TerminPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:TerminPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

Icon="tab_team.png" and Icon="tab_calendar.png" is shown in the Flyout not in the tabbar in the bottom.

[image]

[image]

I have checked the properties (filelocation, size, build action) of the Images themself, and they are the same as for the Icon="tab_feed.png", which is working fine.

Do you have any hint, what can be wrong with the images.

Comment: The icons of the Toolbar may be tinted in Shell. Plase use a monochrome png with transparent background (such as the tab_feed.png) to display the icon. Try to make the image transparent and test again. Similar issue: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/185681/xamarin-forms-tabbedpage-iconimagesource-not-showing-in-ios

Comment: @JarvanZhang-MSFT thanks, to make the png transparent solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons of the `Toolbar` may be tinted in `Shell`. Plase use a monochrome png with transparent background (such as the tab_feed.png) to display the icon. Try to make the image transparent and test again.

Similar issue: 
 https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/185681/xamarin-forms-tabbedpage-iconimagesource-not-showing-in-ios